# functions.php conditional tag only for custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, get-posts, conditional-tags

I'm using gpp slideshow, which overwrites wordpress's default gallery display. I only want to use it on my custom post type, "listings" - how would I reference it to only replace wordpress's default gallery on the "listings' page?

I have this code in my functions.php, and I can't seem to get the reference right for the custom post type:

```
add_action('wp_head','add_gpp_gallery');
function add_gpp_gallery() {
    if( ( is_single() || is_page() ) && ( !is_page_template('page-blog.php') ) ){
        remove_shortcode('gallery', 'gallery_shortcode');
        add_shortcode('gallery', 'gpp_gallery_shortcode');
    }
}
```

above is the code the plugin uses, and I added it to my functions.php and tried this change:

```
if (is_single() && is_post_type('post_type'){
```

and that returns an error.

thoughts & thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using [`get_post_type()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_type) instead:

```
if ( is_single() && 'post_type' == get_post_type() ) {
    // Do something
}
```

The `is_post_type()` conditional is deprecated. But even when it existed, it returned true if *the current post is any registered custom post type*. It has been replaced with [`post_type_exists()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_type_exists).

([More information on Post Type conditional tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags#A_Post_Type).)

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be missing a parenthesis. Try:

```
if (is_single() && is_post_type('post_type')) {
```