# Override plugin with functions.php

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, functions

```
add_action('wp_head','add_gpp_gallery');
function add_gpp_gallery() {
    if( ( is_single() || is_page() ) && ( !is_page_template('page-blog.php') ) ){
        remove_shortcode('gallery', 'gallery_shortcode');
        add_shortcode('gallery', 'gpp_gallery_shortcode');
    }
}
```

Hi All, I pulled the above function out of the plugin's core functions file, and I was hoping to change it to only replace the WP default gallery on my custom post type. So I changed the if statement above to:

```
if (is_single() && is_post_type('post_type'){
```

So I changed it and put it into my functions.php - but I'm getting an error that stating that I can't redeclare add_gpp_gallery

How would I override the plugin's functions without touching the plugin code?

thanks

**EDIT**

I tried:

```
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'add_gpp_gallery' );
add_action('wp_head','jason_add_gpp_gallery');
function jason_add_gpp_gallery() {
    if ( is_single() && is_post_type('listings') ){
        remove_shortcode('gallery', 'gallery_shortcode');
        add_shortcode('gallery', 'gpp_gallery_shortcode');
    }
}
```

and I get a fatal error -

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function is_post_type() in
>   /home/hostspro/public_html/movemaine.com/wp-content/themes/movemaine/functions.php
>   on line 269

**EDIT #2**

I had cross wired my functions, and was forgetting to change out the is_post_type.
The following code is working and thanks for the help

```
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'add_gpp_gallery' );
add_action('wp_head','jason_add_gpp_gallery');
function jason_add_gpp_gallery() {
    if ( is_single() && 'listings' == get_post_type() ) {
        remove_shortcode('gallery', 'gallery_shortcode');
        add_shortcode('gallery', 'gpp_gallery_shortcode');
    }
}
```

Comment: You can shorten your conditional from `is_single() && 'listings' = get_post_type()` to `is_singular('listings')`.  The fatal error is because there is no `is_post_type` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can **change the name of** `add_gpp_gallery` **function** both in the callback and in the declaration to avoid the conflict between the original and your clone.

Something like this...

```
add_action('wp_head','jason_add_gpp_gallery');
function jason_add_gpp_gallery() {
    if ( is_single() && 'your_post_type' == get_post_type() ) ){
        remove_shortcode('gallery', 'gallery_shortcode');
        add_shortcode('gallery', 'gpp_gallery_shortcode');
    }
}
```

... should work for you.

Bonus: You can remove the original plugin action with [remove_action()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action) if needed.

Comment: Note that creating a unique function names anytime you write a function is considered an important practice as it prevents the exact conflicts you're experiencing. See [Objective Best Practices for Plugin Development](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/715/2110)

Comment: The "Bonus" is actually the answer. You need to call `remove_action( 'wp_head', 'add_gpp_gallery' )`, and then call your custom code (with properly namespaced function names).

Comment: @Chip Thanks for clarifing this! No need to keep both of them.

Comment: Unfortunately - I get an error - see edit.

Comment: Umm, [see your previous question, where you asked about `is_post_type()`](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26202/functions-php-conditional-tag-only-for-custom-post-type)?

Comment: @Jason this is an error I copypasted from your example and it's completly unrelated to the problem solved by this answer. The problem is there is no function `is_post_type` in WP. Take a [look](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags#A_Post_Type) at `get_post_type()`

Comment: By the looks of things your function.php is being ran before all the WP core has loaded, specifically `is_post_type()`...

Comment: @Dunhamzzz You are joking right?

Comment: Why else would OP get a function not defined error to a function that does in fact exist?

Comment: @Dunhamzzz Deprecated, see Chip Bennet's comment above pointing to the OP previous Q